# iPhone SDK: Is viewDidUnload called on dealloced viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Is the viewDidUnload method called even if the view controller is dealloced? It seems natural that it´s not called, but I cannot find an answer.

In that case objects released in the viewDidUnload: also need to be released in dealloc, right?

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not called, and yes, they should be released in the view controller's dealloc method; However, there's one stipulation:  Everything you release in the `viewDidUnload` method should be set to `nil` so that if the view is unloaded and later released without being re-loaded you don't over-release anything.